# Trying to systematically change the value of every other row based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that is structured in the ways outlined below. Based on a specific condition, I would like to assign a new value for every other row where this condition is true. I'm wondering if someone can help me assign new values for every other row where a condition occurs and retain these changes in my main data frame.

In my data, each person has received scores from each type of rater. There is rater 1, rater2, and Other. Everyone in my data set should have one rating from each of these three raters. However, some people have scores from two "Other" raters. So in the cases where people have scores from two "Other" raters, I would like to label the second "Other" rater "Other2". I was trying to do this with the code I outlined below,  but I quickly realized that by using the "filter" command, I would not be able to un-filter this and retain the changes I've made in my broader data set.

Here is my current code:

```
d %>% filter(rater=="Other") %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(n()>1) %>% mutate(rater= case_when(ifelse(row_number()%%2==0,"Other2",rater))
```

Below I show what my data currently looks like and how I want my data to look.

Here is what my data currently looks like :

| id | rater | raterscore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rater2 | 3 |
| 1 | rater1 | 2 |
| 1 | Other | 3 |
| 2 | rater1 | 1.5 |
| 2 | rater2 | 3.2 |
| 2 | Other | 1.1 |
| 2 | Other | 2 |
| 3 | rater1 | 2.5 |
| 3 | rater2 | 2.7 |
| 3 | Other | 2.1 |
| 3 | Other | 2 |
| 4 | rater1 | 2.5 |
| 4 | rater2 | 2.7 |
| 4 | Other | 2.1 |
| 4 | Other | 2 |
| 5 | rater1 | 2.5 |
| 5 | rater2 | 2.7 |
| 5 | Other | 2.1 |

Here is what I WANT my data to look like (you'll notice that the second "Other" rater has been changed to "Other2":

| id | rater | raterscore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rater2 | 3 |
| 1 | rater1 | 2 |
| 1 | Other | 3 |
| 2 | rater1 | 1.5 |
| 2 | rater2 | 3.2 |
| 2 | Other | 1.1 |
| 2 | Other**2** | 2 |
| 3 | rater1 | 2.5 |
| 3 | rater2 | 2.7 |
| 3 | Other | 2.1 |
| 3 | Other**2** | 2 |
| 4 | rater1 | 2.5 |
| 4 | rater2 | 2.7 |
| 4 | Other | 2.1 |
| 4 | Other**2** | 2 |
| 5 | rater1 | 2.5 |
| 5 | rater2 | 2.7 |
| 5 | Other | 2.1 |

Can someone help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Typos in last two rows of desired output?

Comment: Yes thank you for catching that! I just fixed it.

Comment: If an id (like 2 in your example data, but not your output) has three Other rater rows, should that last one be Other, Other2, or Other3? I answered thinking "Other3", TarJae answered with "Other", but it's also possible you'd want Other2.... ?

Comment: Your id's change between the two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Other_count = cumsum(rater == "Other"),
         rater = if_else(rater == "Other" & Other_count > 1,
                         "Other2",  # EDIT
                         rater)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Other_count)
```

Result below. Bsed on your description I suspect there are typos in your last two rows of desired output. Row ten seems to be the third Other for id 2, and row 11 is the first Other for id 3.

```
# A tibble: 11 × 3
      id rater  raterscore
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>
 1     1 rater2        3  
 2     1 rater1        2  
 3     1 Other         3  
 4     2 rater1        1.5
 5     2 rater2        3.2
 6     2 Other         1.1
 7     2 Other2        2  
 8     3 rater1        2.5
 9     2 rater2        2.7
10     2 Other2        2.1
11     3 Other         2
```

Comment: Hi your solution comes a lot closer to what I wanted except I was hoping for every time there is more than 1 "other" rater that the second "Other" rater would be called "Other2". I expanded my example data frame titled "Here's what I WANT my dataframe to look like" so it's clear what I'm hoping to see. Thank you so much for your help with this!

Comment: Edited above to make all subsquent Other appearances be Other2.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the typo is in the id column row 9 and 10 should be 3:

Here is how we could do it:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate( x = cumsum(rater == "Other"),
          x = ifelse(x == 2, 2, "")) %>% 
  mutate(rater = paste0(rater, x), .keep="unused")
```

More elegant with `dplyr >= 1.1.0`

```
df %>% 
  mutate( x = cumsum(rater == "Other"),
          x = ifelse(x == 2, 2, ""), .by=id) %>% 
  mutate(rater = paste0(rater, x), .keep="unused")
```

```
      id rater  raterscore
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>
 1     1 rater2        3  
 2     1 rater1        2  
 3     1 Other         3  
 4     2 rater1        1.5
 5     2 rater2        3.2
 6     2 Other         1.1
 7     2 Other2        2  
 8     3 rater1        2.5
 9     3 rater2        2.7
10     3 Other         2.1
11     3 Other2        2
```